# Magento: Add child block programmatically

Tags: magento

I have this block in layout file:

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
```

And this block:

```
$item_block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('catalog/product_list','item')->setTemplate('sns/ajaxcart/catalog/product/item.phtml')->setData('product', $product);
```

How do I have the upper block as $item_block's child programmatically? I know it should be something like:

```
$upper_block = <create upper block>;
$item_block->setChild('somealias',$upper_block);
```

However, the upper block seems to be too complicate for me to know how to create it programmatically. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$upper_block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout') ->createBlock('core/template_facade', "product.info.container2");
$upper_block->setDataByKey('alias_in_layout', 'container2');
$upper_block->setDataByKeyFromRegistry('options_container', 'product');
$upper_block->append('product.info.options.wrapper');
$upper_block->append('product.info.options.wrapper.bottom');

$item_block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('catalog/product_list','item')->setTemplate('sns/ajaxcart/catalog/product/item.phtml')->setData('product', $product);

$item_block->setChild('somealias',$upper_block);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the block level you can do it like this:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
    $this->setChild('items', $block);
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```